# Monotonicity in DFA analysis

Tags: lattice-orders

I am studying program analysis and synthesis, I was reading a presentation
about some DFA analysis.

I can't seem to understand why $$\bigcap_{s'\in\text{pred (s)}}\text{Out}(s')$$
and $$\operatorname{Gen}(s)\cup(\operatorname{In}(s)\setminus \operatorname{Kill}(s))$$ is monotone, as claimed in
[slide 22](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2003/cmsc631/lectures/l02.pdf).

I don't even understand exactly what is the function that is claimed to be monotone.
Can anyone please help ? any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If anyone can think of any other tags that fit please feel free to edit